# How to redirect my application after authentication using twitter

Tags: android, twitter

I am a newbie with android, and I found a code that allows me to authenticate using the twitter api, the problem here is that my application is redirecting to a web page (the CALLBACK URL) and it's working fine, but I want it to redirect to it self (after the authentication phase).

here is the code:

```
package com.androidhive.twitterconnect;
import com.androidhive.twitterconnect.R;

import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// Constants
/**
 * Register your here app https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new and get your
 * consumer key and secret
 * */
static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "****************";
static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET =  "****************************************";

// Preference Constants
static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";

static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "http://google.com";

// Twitter oauth urls
static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";

// Login button
Button btnLoginTwitter;
// Update status button
Button btnUpdateStatus;
// Logout button
Button btnLogoutTwitter;
// EditText for update
EditText txtUpdate;
// lbl update
TextView lblUpdate;
TextView lblUserName;

// Progress dialog
ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Twitter
private static Twitter twitter;
private static RequestToken requestToken;

// Shared Preferences
private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

// Internet Connection detector
private ConnectionDetector cd;

// Alert Dialog Manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // Check if twitter keys are set
    if(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0 || TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0){
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Twitter oAuth tokens", "Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // All UI elements
    btnLoginTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginTwitter);
    btnUpdateStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateStatus);
    btnLogoutTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogoutTwitter);
    txtUpdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUpdateStatus);
    lblUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUpdate);
    lblUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUserName);

    // Shared Preferences
    mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            "MyPref", 0);

    /**
     * Twitter login button click event will call loginToTwitter() function
     * */
    btnLoginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Call login twitter function
            loginToTwitter();
        }
    });

    /**
     * Button click event to Update Status, will call updateTwitterStatus()
     * function
     * */
    btnUpdateStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Call update status function
            // Get the status from EditText
            String status = txtUpdate.getText().toString();

            // Check for blank text
            if (status.trim().length() > 0) {
                // update status
                new updateTwitterStatus().execute(status);
            } else {
                // EditText is empty
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter status message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * Button click event for logout from twitter
     * */
    btnLogoutTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Call logout twitter function
            logoutFromTwitter();
        }
    });

    /** This if conditions is tested once is
     * redirected from twitter page. Parse the uri to get oAuth
     * Verifier
     * */
    if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
            // oAuth verifier
            String verifier = uri
                    .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

            try {
                // Get the access token
                AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                        requestToken, verifier);

                // Shared Preferences
                Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();

                // After getting access token, access token secret
                // store them in application preferences
                e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                        accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                // Store login status - true
                e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                e.commit(); // save changes

                Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());

                // Hide login button
                btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // Show Update Twitter
                lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // Getting user details from twitter
                // For now i am getting his name only
                long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                String username = user.getName();

                // Displaying in xml ui
                lblUserName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Welcome " + username + "</b>"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Check log for login errors
                Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

 }

/**
 * Function to login twitter
 * */
private void loginToTwitter() {
    // Check if already logged in
    if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        Configuration configuration = builder.build();

        TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        twitter = factory.getInstance();

        try {
            requestToken = twitter
                    .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                    .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        // user already logged into twitter
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }

  /**
  * Function to update status
  * */
class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Updating to twitter...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting Places JSON
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + args[0]);
        String status = args[0];
        try {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

            // Access Token
            String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
            // Access Token Secret
            String access_token_secret =  mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

            AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

            // Update status
            twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);

            Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // Error in updating status
            Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog and show
     * the data in UI Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI
     * from background thread, otherwise you will get error
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Status tweeted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                // Clearing EditText field
                txtUpdate.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

  }

 /**
 * Function to logout from twitter
 * It will just clear the application shared preferences
 * */
 private void logoutFromTwitter() {
    // Clear the shared preferences
    Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
    e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN);
    e.remove(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET);
    e.remove(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN);
    e.commit();

    // After this take the appropriate action
    // I am showing the hiding/showing buttons again
    // You might not needed this code
    btnLogoutTwitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btnUpdateStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    txtUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    lblUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    lblUserName.setText("");
    lblUserName.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    btnLoginTwitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }

 /**
 * Check user already logged in your application using twitter Login flag is
 * fetched from Shared Preferences
 * */
 private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
    // return twitter login status from Shared Preferences
    return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
 }

 protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
 }

 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I hope you have properly set **CALLBACK URL** in the application page in twitter. What I did for this case is declaring an `Activity` say `TwitterActivity`. The code snippet for `TwitterActivity` is

```
public class TwitterActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;
    private String url;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.twitter_activity);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        url = extras.getString("AuthUrl");

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.twitter_webview);

        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

        progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(TwitterActivity.this,
                "Please wait", "Loading...");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putExtra("ReturnUrl", url);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.d("tag", "Finished loading URL: " + url);
                if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

}
```

The method `loginToTwitter()` is given below,

```
private void loginToTwitter() {
        // Check if already logged in
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            new TwitterLoginManager().execute(this);
        } else {
            // user already logged into twitter
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            tweet(); // already logged in, you can tweet
        }
    }
```

In the `MainActivity` use `AsyncTask` for fetching **Request Token** . Because `getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)` is a method that makes **HTTP** request. Calling this from UI thread makes unexpected error. Here goes the `AsyncTask` class I used for this purpose.

```
class TwitterLoginManager extends AsyncTask<Activity, Void, Void> {

        String authUrl;
        Activity caller;

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Activity... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            caller = params[0];
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Configuration configuration = builder.build();

            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
            twitter = factory.getInstance();

            try {
                requestToken = twitter
                        .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                authUrl = requestToken.getAuthenticationURL();

            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                Log.d("tag", "Twitter Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog and show
         * the data in UI Always use runOnUiThread(new Runnable()) to update UI
         * from background thread, otherwise you will get error
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(Void ignoreThis) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(caller, TwitterActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("AuthUrl", authUrl);
            caller.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }

    }
```

Also add the callback given below in your `MainActivity`,

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String url=data.getStringExtra("ReturnUrl");
                Log.d("tag","return: "+url);
                getAccessTokenForTwitter(Uri.parse(url));
            }
        }
    }
```

For getting **AccessToken** for twitter, the method is given below,

```
  private void getAccessTokenForTwitter(Uri uri) {

            if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
                Log.d("msg", "Uri: " + uri);
                if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                    // oAuth verifier
                    String verifier = uri
                            .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

                    try {
                        // Get the access token
                        accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken,
                                verifier);

                        Log.d("msg", "access token: " + accessToken);

                        // Shared Preferences
                        Editor e = LoginInfoSharedPreferences.edit();

                        // After getting access token, access token secret
                        // store them in application preferences
                        e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                        e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                                accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                        // Store login status - true
                        e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                        e.commit(); // save changes

                        Log.d("msg", "Token > " + accessToken.getToken());

                        // Getting user details from twitter
                        // For now i am getting his name only
                        long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                        User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                        String username = user.getName();
                        Log.d("tag", "user name: "  + username);
                        tweet();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // Check log for login errors
                        Log.d("tag", "Login Error > " + e.getCause().toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

From the `tweet()` method, update the status for twitter using `UpdateTwitterStatus` class,

```
private void tweet() {
        String status = "Your tweet";

        // Check for blank text
        if (status.trim().length() > 0) {
            // update status
            new UpdateTwitterStatus().execute(status);
        } else {
            /* In case if you use an EditText, then this condition might be necessary for
               checking empty tweet.
            */
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter status",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```